# Variable defined in beforeAll block showing as undefined within `it` name

Tags: jestjs

I'm encountering an issue with Jest where a variable defined within a `beforeAll` block appears as `undefined` when used in the name parameter of the `it` test closure. Here's a simplified version of my code structure:

```
describe('Your test suite', () => {
  let name;

  beforeAll(() => {
    name = 'someValue';
  });

  it(`should say ${name}`, () => {
    expect(name).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Running this returns `should say undefined`, but you can see test is passed because it is actually defined when the test closure is executed.

[image]

Fyi, I know the execution order of the closures. [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69204438/10362396)

Currently I am using the approach where I am defining variables before describe (ditching beforeAll approach)

```
const name = 'someValue';
describe('Your test suite', () => {
  it(`should say ${name}`, () => {
    expect(name).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

[image]

Is there any way I could define `name` in `beforeAll` such that it can be rendered in `it`.

Comment: No, because the names are determined at test discovery time, and the hooks are run at test execution time.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks for confirming.